# wso2 esb jms binding

Tags: jms, wso2, esb

ESB Proxy service is currently listening to IBM MQ Queue using .binding file via JMS transport. 
We have another queue created to meet another functional requirement - do we need to update existing .binding file or create new .binding file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this by updating existing .binding file